# Why DRB translated "prudens", and "prudentes" as "wise" in some verses, While was forced to translate them as "prudent" in some other verses?

Tags: word-study, textual-criticism, latin-vulgate, douay-rheims

I consider- through my research- Latin Vulgate as the most reliable and authentic text of the Bible.

DRB (Douay-Rheims Bible), I consider, the most loyal, literal English translation of the Latin Vulgate.

In spite of this, DRB has some inaccuracies, some illogical mistakes.

For example:

The Latin Vulgate used the word "prudens" and "prudentes", the meaning of these two words is clear to be "prudent" and "discreet". These meanings are clearly distinguished from "wise".

DRB translated the two words as "wise" in some verses, and was forced to translate them to the exact meaning, i.e: "prudent" in some other verses.

Look:

- Matthew 24:45.
- Matthew 25:2,4,9.
- Luke 12:42.
- Ephesians 1:8.
- 1 Corinthians 1:19.

> Matthew 24:45, (DRB):
>   Who, thinkest thou, is a faithful and **wise** servant,...

Matthew 24:45, (LV):
quis putas est fidelis servus et **prudens**...

> Matthew 25:2, (DRB):
>   And five of them were foolish, and five **wise.**

Matthew 25:2, (LV):
quinque autem ex eis erant fatuae et quinque **prudentes.**

> Ephesians 1:8 (DRB):
>   Which hath superabounded in us in all **wisdom** and **prudence,**

Ephesians 1:8 (LV):
quae superabundavit in nobis in omni **sapientia** et **prudentia**

How and why did DRB make such these mistakes?

Comment: Because words in one language don't mean exactly the same thing as words in another language.

Comment: @Curiousdannii I don't agree with you, we can give the exact translation between different languages. When you study my question you will get my point of view.

Comment: I'd suggest you give this book a read, it's excellent and not very long: [Exegetical Fallacies by D. A. Carson](https://www.amazon.com/Exegetical-Fallacies-D-Carson/dp/0801020867).

Comment: @curiousdannii is this book for free?, I have no credit card.

Comment: I agree that it would be helpful to always translate a Greek word by the same English word, but sometimes that is not possible. Words do have a spectrum of meaning and in different contexts another word is sometimes more suitable to precisely convey the concept. These are difficult decisions in translation. An example is the Greek word _psuche_ which is sometimes translated soul and sometimes life. We do not have a similar word to _psuche_ in English.. . . .

Comment: . . . . One way out of the conundrum is to transliterate : in effect to invent a new English word 'psuche' which only works if the reader has grasped the breadth of the Greek word.

Comment: @NigelJ surely, transliteration is sometimes a good solution.

Comment: @salah Well, as I say, only for an educated readership who understand the breadth of the transliterated word. Sometimes we take Greek words into English 'meta' prefix for example, and then don't actually copy the exact Greek usage. 'Anti-' (the prefix) in English means something different to the Greek word and prefix _ante_.

Comment: @NigelJ all these matters are to be taken in account during the project of translation.

Comment: Yes. I spent several years pondering the proper translation of the important words 'Abraham believed God and it was accounted to him for righteousness'. It took me that length of time until I was satisfied I had a better translation. And still I ponder it.

Comment: @NigelJ studying the Sacred texts is the heavenly food to the believers.

Comment: No I don't think it's available for free, but you can find other summaries on blogs etc

Comment: @curiousdannii - Looks like an interesting book.  I just ordered it on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your examples, the DRB tries to use "wise" when possible. However, in the last example, "wise" was used to translate "sapientia", thus forcing a different translations of "prudentia". This is a common problem when translating pairs of synonyms.

Translation is not simply a matter of mapping a word in the source language to the same word in the target language in every case. In fact, doing so can lead to errors. Rather than seeing what the translators did as mistakes, I suggest looking for what motivated them to translate as they did.

Answer (score 1):

They are not really mistakes.

According to the *Complete Oxford English Dictionary*, one of the definitions of the English word "wise" that was in use in 1582 when the Douay-Rheims was written (and still is today) was:

> Having or exercising sound judgement or discernment; capable of
>   judging truly concerning what is right or fitting, and disposed to act
>   accordingly; having the ability to perceive and adopt the best means
>   for accomplishing an end; **characterized by good sense and prudence**

It further cites the use of "prudent" as a synonym for "wise" dating back to the 14th century.

So strictly speaking it was not really a mistake for the DRB translators to use "wise" and "prudent" somewhat interchangeably.

Comment: even if they are synonyms. The translation is a project, I mean the translators should design for the project of translation before they start the process of translation. How is it acceptable to you use a word for a word then I find myself forced to use another word for the same word. I hope you get my point of view.

Comment: @salah - Trying to keep up with you here, but it is difficult.  Are you arguing against the use of synonyms in Bible translation?

Comment: I mean how to use "wise" for a word then I find myself forced to use "prudent" for the same word?, Why not does the translator use "prudent" in all words?. I think my point of view is clear.